# hotkey 3.0037 error on startup

Tags: drivers

When I start up my laptop, I get a error box saying "System needs to be restarted again."
The error message comes from a driver for my CLEVO 761CUH mothervoard. The driver is called hotkey 3.0037 Win 7. The hotkey application provides Energy Sat Power conservation modes. Ive downloaded the latest driver and same error occurs. How will it affect my laptop if I just uninstalled this application/driver ? Is hotkey 3.0037 essential ? How do I fix the error ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Sager NP5160 notebook that also uses hotkey v3.30044 and I also have been getting the same error repeatedly. From what I can see, Hotkey provides visual cues whenever I press certain Fn keys.

For example, when I press Fn + F1 (which will enable/disable my touchpad), Hotkey displays a message saying the touchpad is enabled/disabled. When either the

> System needs to be restarted

message pops up or I manually shut down Hotkey, those messages will not appear, although the Fn keys do still work.

The only way that I've found to fix the "system needs to be restarted" error is uninstall and reinstall the program, although sometimes I've needed to do that a few times to make it work and it may not stay working for long. So you can uninstall it if you want, the only downside being there will be no visual cues to the Fn keys.

It's up to you if the visual cues for the Fn keys are worth putting up with the hit or miss nature of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking "Run as administrator" under Compatibility settings (right click, Properties). Initial observations indicate that it's working.